# Linux daemon localhost works but not the actual IP

Tags: c, linux, sockets, service, daemon

I am learning APUE.2e (Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment, Second Edition) these days and have got to the chapter 16 Network IPC: sockets. When I run the program `ruptime` (for the client end) and `ruptimed` (for the server end), something weird happened. The client program shows a client command that communicates with a server to obtain the output from a
system's `uptime` command, and the server program `ruptimed` (note the 'd') receives the command, exec's the `uptime` command and return the output of `uptime` to the client. The two programs compiled OK, and I add the `ruptime   4000/tcp` to the file `/etc/service` which means the service `ruptime` binds to the port `4000/tcp`. I ran the two programs on the same machine (Ubuntu 11.04) and the `ruptimed` first (of course):

```
$ ./ruptimed
$ ./ruptime 127.0.0.1
 21:35:48 up 13:06,  3 users,  load average: 0.56, 0.85, 0.94
```

The output is what I have expected. However, when I ran:

```
$ ./ruptimed
$ ./ruptime 192.168.1.221
  # the terminal blocks here
```

The IP address 192.168.1.221 is the machine's actual IP in the intranet. What's wrong here? I searched the Internet, and found out it seems to need a shell script in the `/etc/init.d/`. Then I add a file named `ruptime` in the `/etc/init.d/` directory. Here it is:

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     ruptimed
# Required-Start:   $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     
# Short-Description:    ruptime
### END INIT INFO
start()
{
    echo "start ruptime"
    /home/tlh1987/apue-practice/tlh-practice/ruptimed
    exit 0;
}
stop()
{
    killall ruptimed
    echo "stop ruptime"
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    start
    ;;
    stop)
    stop
    ;;
    restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
    *)
    echo "usage: $0 start|stop|restart"
    exit 0;
esac
```

However, it didn't work and I don't know why. I also set the ufw enabled and allowed ruptime
like this:

```
sudo ufw allow ruptime
```

It didn't work either. The source code for `ruptime` and `ruptimed` are as follows:

#### connect_retry()

```
// the  functions used in the two program
// the  connect_retry() function 
#include "apue.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define MAXSLEEP 128

int
connect_retry(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t alen)
{
  int nsec;

  for (nsec = 1; nsec <= MAXSLEEP; nsec <<= 1) {
    if (connect(sockfd, addr, alen) == 0) {
      return (0);
    }
    if (nsec <= MAXSLEEP/2)
      sleep(nsec);
  }
  return (-1);
}
```

#### init_server()

```
// the initserver function 
#include "apue.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int
initserver(int type, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t alen, 
       int qlen)
{
  int fd;
  int err = 0;
  if ((fd = socket(addr->sa_family, type, 0)) < 0)
    return (-1);
  if (bind(fd, addr, alen) < 0) {
    err = errno;
    goto errout;
  }
  if (type == SOCK_STREAM || type == SOCK_SEQPACKET) {
    if (listen(fd, qlen) < 0) {
      err = errno;
      goto errout;
    }
  }
  return(fd);

 errout:
  close(fd);
  errno = err;
  return (-1);
}
```

#### The client end

```
// the client end i.e. ruptime.c
#include "apue.h"
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define MAXADDRLEN 256

#define BUFLEN 128
extern int connect_retry(int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);

void
print_uptime(int sockfd)
{
  int n;
  char buf[BUFLEN];

  while ((n = recv(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0)) > 0)
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);
  if (n < 0)
    err_sys("recv error");
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct addrinfo   *ailist, *aip;
  struct addrinfo    hint;
  int            sockfd, err;

  if (argc !=2 )
    err_quit("usage: ruptime hostname");
  hint.ai_flags = 0;
  hint.ai_family = 0;
  hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hint.ai_protocol = 0;
  hint.ai_addrlen = 0;
  hint.ai_canonname = NULL;
  hint.ai_addr = NULL;
  hint.ai_next = NULL;
  if ((err = getaddrinfo(argv[1], "ruptime", &hint, &ailist)) != 0)
    err_quit("getaddrinfo error: %s", gai_strerror(err));
  for (aip = ailist; aip != NULL; aip = aip->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = socket(aip->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
      err = errno;
    if (connect_retry(sockfd, aip->ai_addr, aip->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
      err = errno;
    } else {
      print_uptime(sockfd);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "can't connect to %s: %s\n", argv[1], 
      strerror(err));
  exit(1);
}
```

#### The server end

```
//the server end i.e. ruptimed is as follows:
#include "apue.h"
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUFLEN 128
#define QLEN 10

#ifndef HOST_NAME_MAX
#define HOST_NAME_MAX 256
#endif

extern int initserver(int, struct sockaddr *, socklen_t, int);

void
serve(int sockfd)
{
  int   clfd;
  FILE *fp;
  char buf[BUFLEN];

  for ( ; ; ) {
    clfd = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);
    if (clfd < 0) {
      syslog(LOG_ERR, "ruptimed: accept error: %s", 
         strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
    }
    if ((fp = popen("/usr/bin/uptime", "r")) == NULL) {
      sprintf(buf, "error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      send(clfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
    } else {
      while (fgets(buf, BUFLEN, fp) != NULL)
    send(clfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
      pclose(fp);
    }
    close(clfd);
  }
}

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct addrinfo   *ailist, *aip;
  struct addrinfo    hint;
  int            sockfd, err, n;
  char          *host;

  if (argc != 1)
    err_quit("usage: ruptimed");
#ifdef _SC_HOST_NAME_MAX
  n = sysconf(_SC_HOST_NAME_MAX);
  if (n < 0)
#endif 
    n = HOST_NAME_MAX;
  host = malloc(n);
  if (host == NULL)
    err_sys("malloc error");
  if (gethostname(host, n) < 0)
    err_sys("gethostname error");
  daemonize("ruptimed");
  hint.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;
  hint.ai_family = 0;
  hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hint.ai_protocol = 0;
  hint.ai_addrlen = 0;
  hint.ai_canonname = NULL;
  hint.ai_addr = NULL;
  hint.ai_next = NULL;
  if ((err = getaddrinfo(host, "ruptime", &hint, &ailist)) != 0) {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "ruptimed: getaddrinfo error: %s", 
       gai_strerror(err));
    exit(1);
  }
  for (aip = ailist; aip != NULL; aip = aip->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = initserver(SOCK_STREAM, aip->ai_addr, 
                 aip->ai_addrlen, QLEN)) >= 0)
      serve(sockfd);
    exit(0);
  }
  exit(1);
}
```

Is there anyone can help?

The header lines of the command netstat -nap:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2252/ruptimed   
tcp        0  13033 192.168.1.221:47380     91.189.89.114:443       LAST_ACK    -               
tcp       74      0 192.168.1.221:43914     91.189.89.76:443        ESTABLISHED 1846/python     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4000          127.0.0.1:56344         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.221:35442     192.168.1.89:24800      SYN_SENT    1478/synergyc   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.221:34957     74.125.71.125:5222      ESTABLISHED 1618/chrome     
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.221:57795     203.208.46.163:443      ESTABLISHED 1618/chrome     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

The 3th record is my service ruptime. Is it something wrong? I don't know much about its meanig.

Comment: Hello I am doing the same exact exercise from the same book (only 3rd edition). I have issues with `getaddrinfo(argv[1], "ruptime", &hint, &ailist)) != 0)` since it cannot find the service `ruptime` where is it in the book how to create such service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a C expert but I know one thing: your daemon is probably binding to just one address/interface, and is accepting connections only from it.

Use `netstat -nap` to check to which address the daemon is binding to.

If it is listening to `0.0.0.0` then it is accepting connections from every interface, including localhost.

If it is listening to `127.0.0.1` it will only accept from localhost.

I bet it's bound only to `127.0.0.1`, that's why you can't connect with any other address.

Comment: I append  the result of the command netstat -nap to the end of the question. Is it something wrong?

Comment: You are right! thank you for the help. I changed the localhost to the 0.0.0.0 in the /etc/hosts and it works.

Comment: @tlh1987 mmm, i don't think that's the correct way to fix it, you should change your server code to make it bind to every interface (0.0.0.0) or the desired interfaces, and leave your localhost /etc/hosts entry as it was before (probably 127.0.0.1). I'm not sure what you should put (i'm not a C guy), but i'm sure you have to change `initserver(SOCK_STREAM, aip->ai_addr, aip->ai_addrlen, QLEN)` from the "server end" code to `initserver(SOCK_STREAM, '0.0.0.0', aip->ai_addrlen, QLEN)` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a firewall issue, not a coding issue.  You might want to look at [some ufw documentation](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ufw-uncomplicated-firewall-for-ubuntu-hardy.html) and specify the port or IP address on your ufw line.

Comment: +1, this is the other possibility (in addition to `netstat` or `lsof -i`)

Comment: @dj_segfault I disabled the ufw, But it didn't work. PS: I can ssh to the machine from another machine.

Comment: @tlh1987 I don't use ufw but I'll take your word for it that you know how to disable the firewall.  I would verify by running WireShark on the server and seeing whether the packets are even getting there when your client sends, but that's me.  But the fact that you can ssh to the machine doesn't mean much since firewall rules are usually port-specific.

Comment: @dj_segfault Yes, you're right, the firewall rules are port-specific, the ufw can block the port 4000 which I use for my service,I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

blocking commands can be difficult to figure out where they hang. so one way is the classical way of network sniffing (`man tcpdump # or ngrep`)

the other is `strace yourcommand` and see where it hangs, fix what the problem is...